# MySQL error 1054 because column is calculate

Tags: mysql

i am trying to add where condition on my query. Need to add debt>0.

```
SELECT 
  tblcustomer.customer_id, 
  tblcustomer.surname, 
  tblcustomer.name, 
  (sum(tblappointment.app_price) - sum(COALESCE(tblappointment.app_price_paid, 0))) as debt 
FROM `tblappointment` 
INNER JOIN `tblcustomer` ON tblcustomer.customer_id = tblappointment.customer_id 
WHERE debt>0 
GROUP BY tblappointment.customer_id 
ORDER BY debt desc;
```

Comment: What's the verbatim error message?

Answer (score 0):

Remove WHERE debt>0 and alter GROUP BY tblappointment.customer_id HAVING DEPT > 0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from (SELECT tblcustomer.customer_id, 
                      tblcustomer.surname, 
                      tblcustomer.name,  
                      (sum(tblappointment.app_price) - sum(COALESCE(tblappointment.app_price_paid, 0))) as debt 
               FROM `tblappointment` 
               INNER JOIN `tblcustomer` ON tblcustomer.customer_id = tblappointment.customer_id 
               GROUP BY tblappointment.customer_id) as NewTable 
WHERE debt > 0 
ORDER BY debt desc
```